# Why runtime dependency doesn't work in gradle?

Tags: gradle, apache-spark

I have a simple spark application and gradle 2.3, spark guide says spark libs need not be bundled, so I uses 'runtime' dependency in build.gradle as following:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'scala'
apply plugin: 'maven'


repositories {

    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.5'
    runtime 'org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.10:1.3.1'
    runtime 'org.apache.spark:spark-streaming_2.10:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.10:1.2.0-rc3'

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

However, when I run 'classes' task, I got errors. That means the compile can't find the jars. I also tried 'provided' and 'providedCompile', the result was "no method provided()/providedCompile() found"

```
[ant:scalac] /Users/grant/programming/ideaprojects/scalaTest/src/main/scala/com/grant/cassandra/DemoApp.scala:3: error: object Logging is not a member of package org.apache.spark
[ant:scalac] import org.apache.spark.{Logging, SparkContext, SparkConf}
[ant:scalac]        ^
[ant:scalac] /Users/grant/programming/ideaprojects/scalaTest/src/main/scala/com/grant/cassandra/DemoApp.scala:5: error: not found: type Logging
[ant:scalac] trait DemoApp extends App with Logging {
[ant:scalac]                                ^
[ant:scalac] /Users/grant/programming/ideaprojects/scalaTest/src/main/scala/com/grant/cassandra/DemoApp.scala:14: error: not found: type SparkConf
[ant:scalac]   val conf = new SparkConf(true)
[ant:scalac]                  ^
[ant:scalac] /Users/grant/programming/ideaprojects/scalaTest/src/main/scala/com/grant/cassandra/DemoApp.scala:21: error: not found: type SparkContext
[ant:scalac]   lazy val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
[ant:scalac]                     ^
[ant:scalac] /Users/grant/programming/ideaprojects/scalaTest/src/main/scala/com/grant/cassandra/WordCountDemo.scala:3: error: object SparkContext is not a member of package org.apache.spark
[ant:scalac] import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
[ant:scalac]                         ^
[ant:scalac] error: bad symbolic reference. A signature in CassandraConnector.class refers to type Logging
[ant:scalac] in package org.apache.spark which is not available.
[ant:scalac] It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
[ant:scalac] the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling CassandraConnector.class.
[ant:scalac] error: bad symbolic reference. A signature in CassandraConnector.class refers to type SparkConf
[ant:scalac] in package org.apache.spark which is not available.
[ant:scalac] It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
[ant:scalac] the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling CassandraConnector.class.
[ant:scalac] /Users/grant/programming/ideaprojects/scalaTest/src/main/scala/com/grant/spark/PairRDDTest.scala:3: error: object SparkConf is not a member of package org.apache.spark
[ant:scalac] import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
[ant:scalac]        ^
[ant:scalac] /Users/grant/programming/ideaprojects/scalaTest/src/main/scala/com/grant/spark/PairRDDTest.scala:4: error: object SparkContext is not a member of package org.apache.spark
[ant:scalac] import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
[ant:scalac]        ^
[ant:scalac] /Users/grant/programming/ideaprojects/scalaTest/src/main/scala/com/grant/spark/PairRDDTest.scala:5: error: object rdd is not a member of package org.apache.spark
[ant:scalac] import org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions
[ant:scalac]                         ^
[ant:scalac] /Users/grant/programming/ideaprojects/scalaTest/src/main/scala/com/grant/spark/PairRDDTest.scala:10: error: not found: type SparkConf
[ant:scalac]         val conf = new SparkConf
[ant:scalac]                        ^
[ant:scalac] /Users/grant/programming/ideaprojects/scalaTest/src/main/scala/com/grant/spark/PairRDDTest.scala:14: error: not found: type SparkContext
[ant:scalac]         val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
[ant:scalac]                      ^
[ant:scalac] /Users/grant/programming/ideaprojects/scalaTest/src/main/scala/com/grant/spark/PairRDDTest.scala:18: error: not found: type PairRDDFunctions
[ant:scalac]         val func = new PairRDDFunctions(rdd)
[ant:scalac]                        ^
[ant:scalac] /Users/grant/programming/ideaprojects/scalaTest/src/main/scala/com/grant/spark/SparkMain.scala:3: error: object SparkConf is not a member of package org.apache.spark
[ant:scalac] import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
[ant:scalac]        ^
[ant:scalac] /Users/grant/programming/ideaprojects/scalaTest/src/main/scala/com/grant/spark/SparkMain.scala:7: error: not found: type SparkConf
[ant:scalac]       val conf = new SparkConf
[ant:scalac]                      ^
[ant:scalac] /Users/grant/programming/ideaprojects/scalaTest/src/main/scala/com/grant/spark/SparkMain.scala:11: error: not found: type SparkContext
[ant:scalac]       val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
[ant:scalac]                    ^
[ant:scalac] 16 errors found
```

Answer (score 1):

`provided`/`providedCompile` configurations do not exist until some plugin or your build script creates them. You can use plugin from [nebula-plugins](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-extra-configurations-plugin) or do it on your like this

```
configurations {
  provided
}
sourceSets {
  main {
    compileClasspath += [configurations.provided]
  }
}
dependencies {
  provided 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:2.5.0-mr1-cdh5.3.0'
  compile ...
  testCompile 'org.apache.mrunit:mrunit:1.0.0'
}
jar {
  doFirst {
    into('lib') { from configurations.runtime }
  }
}
idea {
  module {
    scopes.PROVIDED.plus += [configurations.provided]
  }
}
```

This example also adds libraries from compile into `lib` folder of your JAR to make it simple to run them as Hadoop job. For Spark you may need to create shaded JAR or "uber" JAR. That will add compile dependencies (not provided).

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I turn to SBT, which has assembly plugin to help build a "uber" jar. however, other problems happen, sigh

Comment: There are a few #fatjar plugins for Gradle. You can search them on plugin portal https://plugins.gradle.org/search?term=fatjar

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the gradle docs ( https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html ) I think runtimes means its only required at runtime. I believe if you switch it to compiled it will be included in runtime as well (the wording is a bit confusing, but if you look at the wording for testCompile it would either mean that everything included for tests was shipped in production code - which would be pretty non-standard - or it means that by default testCompile includes all of the compile elements, much like with runtime).